# BX slider not showing properly in safari for windows

Tags: html, css, safari

Hi guys this is my html page which works fine in chrome, firefox but in safari it shrinks. Am I missing something

This is my url
http://spheretekk.com/glamrs/profiler.html

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure try to add the width for .skintoneb class like below..

```
.skintoneb
{
 text-align:center;
 width:800px;
}
```

Comment: I cant give px as its responsive...I feel it has something to do with display:inliine-block, when i do it to float left it works sometimes.

Comment: oh ok can you add the width property for skintone-box class. Right now it has only max-width property.    .skintone-box{width:24%;}

Comment: Hi Suresh I managed to do it. Just added the float left and removed the inline block. Thanks a lot dude anyway